# Why can't I find anything on this command on the net? `statftime`

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, command

**PROBLEM:**

I'm learning `bash` from books(Linux Shell Scripting with Bash, Ken O. Burch) and this book I'm following now is using this command:

`/usr/bin/statftime`

but I can't find this command for my Linux

I'm using Debian 9.0 stretch

**QUESTION:**

Can you tell me about this command and if it's possible to install it on Debian and how to install it on Debian?

**EDIT:**

The book is one of the best `bash` books(Linux Shell Scripting with Bash, Ken O. Burch) I've read(@Gilles) so this is probably not a trick and I'll post the code below:

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#
# polling.sh: a daemon using polling to check for new files

shopt -s -o nounset

declare -rx SCRIPT=${0##*/}
declare -rx INCOMING_FTP_DIR="/home/ftp/ftp_incoming"
declare -rx PROCESSING_DIR="/home/ftp/processing"
declare -rx statftime="/usr/local/bin/statftime"
declare FILE=""
declare FILES=""
declare NEW_FILE=""

printf "$SCRIPT started at %s\n" "`date`"

# Sanity checks
if [[ ! -d /home/ftp/ftp_incoming ]] || [[ ! -d /home/ftp/processing ]]
then
    mkdir -p /home/ftp/ftp_incoming
    mkdir -p /home/ftp/processing
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "You are a idiot"
    else
        echo "You succeded!"
    fi
fi
if test ! -r "$INCOMING_FTP_DIR"
then
    printf "%s\n" "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: unable to read the incoming directory --aborted" >&1
    exit 1
fi
if test ! -r "$PROCESSING_DIR"
then
    printf "%s\n" "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: unable to read the incoming directory --aborted" >&1
    exit 1
fi
if test ! -r "$statftime"
then
    printf "%s\n" "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: unable to find or execute $statftime --aborted" >&1
    exit 1
fi

# Poll for new FTP files

cd $INCOMING_FTP_DIR
while true
do
    #check for new files more than 30 minutes unchanged
    FILES=`find . -type f -mmin +30 -print`

    # If new files exist, move them to the processing directory

    if [ ! -z "$FILES" ]
    then
        printf "$SCRIPT: new files have arrived at %s\n" "`date`"
        printf "%s\n" "$FILES" |
        {
            while read FILE
            do
                # Remove leading "./"
                FILE=${FILE##*/}
                # Rename the file with the current time
                NEW_FILE=`$statftime -f "%_L%_a_%T.dat" "$FILE"`
                if [ -z "$NEW_FILE" ]
                then
                    printf "%s\n" "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: statftime failed to create a new filename--skipping"
                else
                    # Move the file to the processing directory
                    printf "%s\n" "$SCRIPT: moved $FILE to $PROCESSING_DIR/$NEW_FILE"
                    mv "$FILE" "$PROCESSING_DIR/$NEW_FILE"
                fi
            done
        }
    fi
    sleep 30
done


printf "$SCRIPT finished unexpectedly at %s\n" "`date`"
exit 1
```

Here is some info on the command:

[search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=statftime&ia=web)

[site](https://www.pegasoft.ca/sft.html)

Comment: [Have you tried using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=statftime&ia=web)? (The same site is at the top of the Google hits for me as well.) If that's not relevant for you, **tell us what this book is and what this command is about**. This has the strong smell of a command written for the book or at least by the author of the book, rather than some standard command you'd expect to find in a distribution.

Comment: [PegaSoft - statftime](https://www.pegasoft.ca/sft.html)

Comment: @eyoung100 thanks alot, if you put it in an answer with some info on the install and the command I will accept your answer

Comment: @someone thanks for the upvote, been getting alot of downvotes on my questions rececntly

Comment: P.S. in the book the dir for statftime is `/usr/bin/statftime` so I thought it was an old program because of the dir it was suppose to be in and the auther doesn't mention any installing a program anywhere

Comment: no comment needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

A simple search via [Google for statftime](https://www.google.com/search?ei=lLfzW4niB4PajwTgw7bQBQ&q=statftime%20&oq=statftime%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13l10.3611.4683..6397...0.0..0.94.511.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i13i30j0i13i10i30.ZIWMajiRGgo) returned the software vendor for the program you're looking for, as the first result.  [PegaSoft](https://www.pegasoft.ca/main.html) looks to be a blog focusing on Linux and the [Ada Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)).

Note that a search for `statftime debian` returns nothing related to the Debian Repositories.  The [install instructions](https://www.pegasoft.ca/sft.html) will require the [build-essential package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/build-essential), with install instructions at: [Debian Linux Install GNU GCC Compiler and Development Environment](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-install-gnu-gcc-compiler/).  Somewhere in your book, I'm sure that link exists as a footnote etc.

Comment: Looks like the author hadn't realise that GNU `find` (with `-printf`) or the `stat` builtin of `zsh`, both from the 90s and predating GNU `stat` could already do the same thing and more (including retrieving information from symlinks which this `statftime` can't do).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I looked at the tools page, and saw that those tools all were rather old.  It looks as if the author is concerned with selling his new product in a niche market.  See also: [SparForte](http://sparforte.com/index.html).